# JBoss AS 7 deployment dilemma, eclipse vs standalone.bat

Tags: eclipse, jakarta-ee, jboss, jboss7.x

![enter image description here][1]I am using Eclipse plug-in to deploy my J2EE application on JBoss AS 7. 
I made changes in JBOSS_HOME/bin/standalone.conf as well as in standalone.conf.bat, where I updated the JVM heap sizes.

If I deploy the application via eclipse, the modified JVM configuriation isn't applied during the server start up. However, when I start it, using the standalone.conf.bat the changes are reflected during the start up as expected.

Is there anything I'm missing that eclipse fails to pick up?

Here is how the standalone.conf reads:

```
#JAVA=""

if [ "x$JBOSS_MODULES_SYSTEM_PKGS" = "x" ]; then
JBOSS_MODULES_SYSTEM_PKGS="org.jboss.byteman"
fi

# Uncomment the following line to prevent manipulation of JVM options
# by shell scripts.
#
#PRESERVE_JAVA_OPTS=true

#
# Specify options to pass to the Java VM.
#
if [ "x$JAVA_OPTS" = "x" ]; then
JAVA_OPTS="-Xms256m -Xmx1024m -XX:MaxPermSize=512m -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -       Dorg.jboss.resolver.warning=true -Dsun.rmi.dgc.client.gcInterval=3600000 - Dsun.rmi.dgc.server.gcInterval=3600000"
JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS -Djboss.modules.system.pkgs=$JBOSS_MODULES_SYSTEM_PKGS - Djava.awt.headless=true"
JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS -Djboss.server.default.config=standalone.xml"
else
  echo "JAVA_OPTS already set in environment; overriding default settings with values: $JAVA_OPTS"
fi
```

standalone.conf.bat:

```
if not "x%JAVA_OPTS%" == "x" (
echo "JAVA_OPTS already set in environment; overriding default settings with values:     %JAVA_OPTS%"
goto JAVA_OPTS_SET
)
rem # JVM memory allocation pool parameters - modify as appropriate.
set "JAVA_OPTS=-Xms64M -Xmx512M -XX:MaxPermSize=256M"

rem # Reduce the RMI GCs to once per hour for Sun JVMs.
set "JAVA_OPTS=%JAVA_OPTS% -Dsun.rmi.dgc.client.gcInterval=3600000 -   Dsun.rmi.dgc.server.gcInterval=3600000 -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true"
```

The eclipse runtime clearly points to c: where i have done the edits to configuration files

![Eclipse Image]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mdq8d.jpg

Comment: did you use jboss tools plugin?

Comment: yes i am using jboss  tools plugin.

Comment: which operating system are you using?

Comment: Windows 8, Eclipse Juno and Jboss 7AS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can specify heap size in VM arguments within eclipse.

`Double click on Server-> Open Launch Configuration -> enter heap size in VM argument`.

Comment: Correct, this is where the eclipse was picking the configuration from and any configuration changes in JBOSS_HOME/ was not getting reflected. Thanks Neeraj.

Answer (score 0):

Since there is no other answer yet, here's my assumption.
Did you made the changes directly under the `JBOSS_HOME/....` or in Eclipse for the JBoss instance? For any reason you can't make the changes under

```
Eclipse -> Server -> JBoss7_Runtime -> Filesets -> Configuration File -> standalone.xml
```

This is different from the Tomcat instance, where it is usual to edit the server.xml configuration file in eclipse as well. May be there is a workaround for the JBoss runtime, so that you can edit the config in eclipse too.

Comment: Yes, i made changes in JBOSS_HOME/.... and eclipse does not pick this up. So clearly eclipse does not use standalone.conf or standalone.conf.bat to start its jboss instance. I am wondring where does eclipse pick the configuration from to start thr jboss instance.

Comment: I strongly assume, that the JBoss server instance (Created in eclipse workspace) knows which scripts need to be used in order to start and stop the server. (That why you need to specify the type of the server `JBoss`, `Tomcat`, etc during create new Server ) Maybe your path to your JBoss server instance on disk isn't correct or point to another server (In case you have several copies of JBoss AS). Check the following: `Eclipse` -> `ServerTab` -> `Runtime Environment` -> `Home Directory` This home directory need to point to the copy of your JBoss where you have edited the configuration files.

Comment: No i do not have several copies of Jboss AS :(

Comment: @amitsalyan Update your answer by adding the modified parts of your configuration files, as well as a screenshot of your Eclipse ServerRuntime overview.